# How to calculate remaining time in custom html5 audio player with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, audio-player

I found a good custom HTML5 audio player and successfully redesigned it for my needs. Everything about it is ok, except it didn't show "remaining" time (how much time actually left to track end).

I want to add a calculation of time left without changing the original script, Is it possible?

[

```js
function calculateTotalValue(length) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60),
    seconds_int = length - minutes * 60,
    seconds_str = seconds_int.toString(),
    seconds = seconds_str.substr(0, 2),
    time = minutes + ':' + seconds

  return time;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
  var current_hour = parseInt(currentTime / 3600) % 24,
    current_minute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60,
    current_seconds_long = currentTime % 60,
    current_seconds = current_seconds_long.toFixed(),
    current_time = (current_minute < 10 ? "0" + current_minute : current_minute) + ":" + (current_seconds < 10 ? "0" + current_seconds : current_seconds);

  return current_time;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/luke__duncan/pen/dpZVOr) (original player source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is extremely easy, You don't have to change a lot of code but just need to add just two lines.

Inside the "initProgressBar()" function just add these two lines of code

//calculate the remaining time

```
var rem_time=length-current_time;
 jQuery(".rem-time").html(calculateCurrentValue(rem_time));
```

//HTML to show the remaining time(add it to the HTML)

```
 <small style="float: left; position: relative; left: 15px;" class="rem-time"></small>
```

the first line is just getting the total seconds, "length" and "current_time" was already available in the code so I am just using them, nothing new.

In the second line, I am converting the remaining time to a readable format, again using an already available function "calculateCurrentValue()" and setting an HTML element with remaining time.

At last the HTML element in which the remaining time will be shown.

You can also take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shubhamkumarnayak/pen/XBOPZJ) which I have done for a better understanding.

Adding Full code here to make sure it is available always

```js
function calculateTotalValue(length) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60),
    seconds_int = length - minutes * 60,
    seconds_str = seconds_int.toString(),
    seconds = seconds_str.substr(0, 2),
    time = minutes + ':' + seconds

  return time;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
  var current_hour = parseInt(currentTime / 3600) % 24,
    current_minute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60,
    current_seconds_long = currentTime % 60,
    current_seconds = current_seconds_long.toFixed(),
    current_time = (current_minute < 10 ? "0" + current_minute : current_minute) + ":" + (current_seconds < 10 ? "0" + current_seconds : current_seconds);

  return current_time;
}
var prevcurrentime=0;
function initProgressBar() {
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  var length = player.duration
  var current_time = player.currentTime;

  // calculate total length of value
  var totalLength = calculateTotalValue(length)
  jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);

  // calculate current value time
  var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
  
  jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);
  //checking if the current time is bigger than the previous or else there will be sync different between remaining and current
  if(currentTime>prevcurrentime){
  //calculate the remaining time
  var rem_time=length-current_time;
 jQuery(".rem-time").html(calculateCurrentValue(rem_time));
  }
  //setting the previouscurrent time to this current time
  prevcurrentime=currentTime;
  //progress bar calculation
  var progressbar = document.getElementById('seekObj');
  progressbar.value = (player.currentTime / player.duration);
  progressbar.addEventListener("click", seek);

  if (player.currentTime == player.duration) {
    $('#play-btn').removeClass('pause');
  }

  function seek(evt) {
    var percent = evt.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
    player.currentTime = percent * player.duration;
    progressbar.value = percent / 100;
  }
};

function initPlayers(num) {
  // pass num in if there are multiple audio players e.g 'player' + i

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    (function() {

      // Variables
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      // audio embed object
      var playerContainer = document.getElementById('player-container'),
        player = document.getElementById('player'),
        isPlaying = false,
        playBtn = document.getElementById('play-btn');

      // Controls Listeners
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      if (playBtn != null) {
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
          togglePlay()
        });
      }

      // Controls & Sounds Methods
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      function togglePlay() {
        if (player.paused === false) {
          player.pause();
          isPlaying = false;
          $('#play-btn').removeClass('pause');

        } else {
          player.play();
          $('#play-btn').addClass('pause');
          isPlaying = true;
        }
      }
    }());
  }
}

initPlayers(jQuery('#player-container').length);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: yellow;
}

.audio-player {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  width: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin: 4rem 0 4rem 0;
}
.audio-player .album-image {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 110px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.audio-player .player-controls {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  flex: 3;
}
.audio-player .player-controls progress {
  width: 90%;
}
.audio-player .player-controls progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  height: 5px;
}
.audio-player .player-controls progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  color: blue;
}
.audio-player .player-controls progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: blue;
}
.audio-player .player-controls p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.audio-player #play-btn {
  background-image: url("http://www.lukeduncan.me/images/play-button.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
}
.audio-player #play-btn.pause {
  background-image: url("http://www.lukeduncan.me/images/pause-button.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="audio-player">
    <div id="play-btn"></div>
    <div class="audio-wrapper" id="player-container" href="javascript:;">
      <audio id="player" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
     <source src="http://www.lukeduncan.me/oslo.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="player-controls scrubber">
      <p>Oslo <small>by</small> Holy Esque</p>
      <span id="seekObjContainer">
     <progress id="seekObj" value="0" max="1"></progress>
   </span>
      <br>
      <small style="float: left; position: relative; left: 15px;" class="start-time"></small><br/>
      <small style="float: left; position: relative; left: 15px;" class="rem-time"></small>
      <small style="float: right; position: relative; right: 20px;" class="end-time"></small>

    </div>
    <div class="album-image" style="background-image: url('https://artwork-cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/051/614/0005161476_350.jpg')"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! Is it possible to "seconds" (time value) in both "start" and "remaining" changes at the same time like in most players?

Comment: Ok, I will do that @AndrewK

Comment: Any luck? @Shubham

Comment: @AndrewK I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @AndrewK sure, why not.

Comment: You answered all my questions, thank you so much! @Shubham

Comment: @AndrewK sorry for the delay, let me check